# Add "name" datatype to custom biblatex entry styles

Tags: biblatex, biber

With the great help of @moewe, i was able to set up a custom biblatex style and since I'll have to create some more, I thought I'd give it a try while I still remember what to do :D

So my **main challenge** now is to get `name` datatype to be printed. I am not sure why, however the printing of my custom fields `producer` and `director` are omitted, while it works perfectly fine to print the predefined `organization`.

The **second challenge** is setting up a condition. If there is no maintitle, I would like the `volume` to be printed differently (instead of between the maintitle and title, after the title).

So instead of this: [image]

the first part should then look like this: 
[image]

This is my current MWE:

```
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true, synctex: true }
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true, synctex: true }
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@video{help,
  maintitle       = {Terasu Hausu},
  date           = {2012-02-26},
  year           = {2012},
  maintitleaddon  = {Terrace House},
  titleaddon = {Boys and Girls In The City},
  title    = {Boisu},
  volume = {2},
  seriesseason = {3},
  episode = {12},
  duration = {54 Minuten},
  director = {Maeda, Masato},
  producer = {Matsumoto, Ayaka and Peters, Greg},
  format = {Video On Demand},
  type = {TV-Mini-Series},
  fsk = {12},
  urldate        = {2019-07-21},
  url            = {https://www.netflix.com/title/80212301},
  organization   = {Netflix}
}

@video{helpshort,
  date           = {2012-02-26},
  year           = {2012},
  titleaddon = {Boys and Girls In The City},
  title    = {Boisu},
  volume = {2},
  seriesseason = {3},
  episode = {12},
  duration = {54 Minuten},
  director = {Maeda, Masato},
  producer = {Matsumoto, Ayaka and Peters, Greg},
  format = {Video On Demand},
  type = {TV-Mini-Series},
  fsk = {12},
  urldate        = {2019-07-21},
  url            = {https://www.netflix.com/title/80212301},
  organization   = {Netflix}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents}{customstyles.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{video}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  duration,
  format,
  type,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  director,
  producer,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=verbatim]{
  fsk,
  seriesseason,
  episode,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[video]{
  duration,
  director,
  episode,
  format,
  fsk,
  producer,
  seriesseason,
  type,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  isbn=false
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

  \DeclareLabeltitle[video]{%
  \field{maintitle}
  \field{shorttitle}
  \field{title}
 } 

\begin{filecontents*}{custombibstring-ngerman.lbx}
\ProvidesFile{custombibstring-ngerman.lbx}[2019/07/26]
\InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit      = {ngerman},
  andothers    = {{et al\adddot}{et al\adddot}},
  byeditor     = {{herausgegeben von}{hg\adddotspace von}},
  editor       = {{Herausgeber}{Hg\adddot}},
  editors      = {{Herausgeber}{Hg\adddot}},
  urlseen      = {{letzter Abruf}{letzter Abruf}},
  duration = {{Spieldauer}{Spieldauer}},
  seriesseason = {{Staffel}{Staffel}},
  episode = {{Episode}{Episode}},
  director = {{unter der Regie von}{unter der Regie von}},
  producer = {{produziert von}{produziert von}},
  fsk = {{FSK}{FSK}},
  volume = {{Vol\adddot}{Vol\adddot}}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\NewBibliographyString{director,duration,episode,format,fsk,producer,seriesseason}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{custombibstring-ngerman}

\renewcommand*{\titleaddonpunct}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldAlias{booktitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{maintitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{subtitleaddon}{titleaddon}

\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{title}{\textit{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{subtitle}{\textit{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{duration}{\bibstring{duration}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{format}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{fsk}{\bibstring{fsk}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{seriesseason}{{#1}\adddot~\bibstring{seriesseason}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{episode}{{#1}\adddot~\bibstring{episode}}
\DeclareListWrapperFormat[video]{organization}{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareListWrapperFormat[video]{director}{\bibstring{director}\addcolon{\textsc{#1}}}
\DeclareListWrapperFormat[video]{producer}{\bibstring{producer}\addcolon{\textsc{#1}}}

\newbibmacro*{titles}{%
  \printfield{maintitle}%
   \setunit*{\titleaddonpunct}%
  \printfield{maintitleaddon}
  \newunit{\addspace}%
   \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace} 
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{\titleaddonpunct}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printdate
}  

\newbibmacro*{format}{%  
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}%
  \printfield{type}%
  \setunit*{\titleaddonpunct}
   \printfield{format}%
}


\newbibmacro*{series}{%
  \printfield{seriesseason}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{episode}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}%
  \printlist{producer}%
  \setunit*{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printlist{director}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}%
  \printfield{duration}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{fsk}%
  \setunit*{\titleaddonpunct}
}

\urlstyle{same}%
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{video}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{titles}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{format}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\cite{help}

\cite{helpshort}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: For future questions it might be more appropriate to ask about the two *challenges* separately. Ideally each question should only be about one specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name lists are printed with the command `\printnames` (instead of `\printlist` or `\printfield`). So you need something like

```
\newbibmacro*{tvseries}{%
  \printfield{seriesseason}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{episode}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}%
  \printnames{producer}%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}%
  \printnames{director}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}%
  \printfield{duration}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{fsk}%
  \setunit*{\titleaddonpunct}%
}
```

For the second issue you'll want to use `\iffieldundef`.

```
\newbibmacro*{titles}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\printfield{maintitle}%
     \setunit*{\titleaddonpunct}%
     \printfield{maintitleaddon}
     \newunit{\addspace}%
     \printfield{volume}%
     \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{\titleaddonpunct}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \printfield{volume}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printdate
}
```

Note that there is a difference between `\adddot` (a dot for abbrevations) and `\addperiod` (a sentence-ending period, full stop).

In total

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@video{help,
  maintitle      = {Terasu Hausu},
  date           = {2012-02-26},
  year           = {2012},
  maintitleaddon = {Terrace House},
  titleaddon     = {Boys and Girls In The City},
  title          = {Boisu},
  volume         = {2},
  seriesseason   = {3},
  episode        = {12},
  duration       = {54 Minuten},
  director       = {Maeda, Masato},
  producer       = {Matsumoto, Ayaka and Peters, Greg},
  format         = {Video On Demand},
  type           = {TV-Mini-Series},
  fsk            = {12},
  urldate        = {2019-07-21},
  url            = {https://www.netflix.com/title/80212301},
  organization   = {Netflix},
}
@video{helpshort,
  date           = {2012-02-26},
  year           = {2012},
  titleaddon     = {Boys and Girls In The City},
  title          = {Boisu},
  volume         = {2},
  seriesseason   = {3},
  episode        = {12},
  duration       = {54 Minuten},
  director       = {Maeda, Masato},
  producer       = {Matsumoto, Ayaka and Peters, Greg},
  format         = {Video On Demand},
  type           = {TV-Mini-Series},
  fsk            = {12},
  urldate        = {2019-07-21},
  url            = {https://www.netflix.com/title/80212301},
  organization   = {Netflix},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents}{customstyles.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{video}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  duration,
  format,
  type,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  director,
  producer,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=verbatim]{
  fsk,
  seriesseason,
  episode,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[video]{
  duration,
  director,
  episode,
  format,
  fsk,
  producer,
  seriesseason,
  type,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  isbn=false
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}


  \DeclareLabeltitle[video]{%
  \field{maintitle}
  \field{shorttitle}
  \field{title}
 } 

\begin{filecontents*}{custombibstring-ngerman.lbx}
\ProvidesFile{custombibstring-ngerman.lbx}[2019/07/26]
\InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit      = {ngerman},
  andothers    = {{et al\adddot}{et al\adddot}},
  byeditor     = {{herausgegeben von}{hg\adddotspace von}},
  editor       = {{Herausgeber}{Hg\adddot}},
  editors      = {{Herausgeber}{Hg\adddot}},
  urlseen      = {{letzter Abruf}{letzter Abruf}},
  duration     = {{Spieldauer}{Spieldauer}},
  seriesseason = {{Staffel}{Staffel}},
  episode      = {{Episode}{Episode}},
  bydirector   = {{unter der Regie von}{unter der Regie von}},
  byproducer   = {{produziert von}{produziert von}},
  fsk          = {{FSK}{FSK}},
  volume       = {{Vol\adddot}{Vol\adddot}},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\NewBibliographyString{bydirector,duration,episode,format,fsk,byproducer,seriesseason}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{custombibstring-ngerman}

\renewcommand*{\titleaddonpunct}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldAlias{booktitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{maintitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{subtitleaddon}{titleaddon}

\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{title}{\textit{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{subtitle}{\textit{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{duration}{\bibstring{duration}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{format}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{fsk}{\bibstring{fsk}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{seriesseason}{\mkbibordinal{#1}~\bibstring{seriesseason}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[video]{episode}{\mkbibordinal{#1}~\bibstring{episode}}
\DeclareListWrapperFormat[video]{organization}{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat[video]{director}{\bibstring{bydirector}\addspace#1}
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat[video]{producer}{\bibstring{byproducer}\addspace#1}

\newbibmacro*{titles}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\printfield{maintitle}%
     \setunit*{\titleaddonpunct}%
     \printfield{maintitleaddon}
     \newunit{\addspace}%
     \printfield{volume}%
     \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{\titleaddonpunct}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \printfield{volume}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printdate
}  

\newbibmacro*{format}{%  
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}%
  \printfield{type}%
  \setunit*{\titleaddonpunct}%
  \printfield{format}%
}


\newbibmacro*{tvseries}{%
  \printfield{seriesseason}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{episode}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}%
  \printnames{producer}%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}%
  \printnames{director}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}%
  \printfield{duration}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{fsk}%
  \setunit*{\titleaddonpunct}%
}

\urlstyle{same}%
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{video}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{titles}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{format}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{tvseries}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\cite{help}

\cite{helpshort}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Terasu Hausu [Terrace House]. Vol. 2: Boisu [Boys and Girls In The City] (26.02.2012). Netflix: TV-Mini-Series (Video On Demand). 3. Staffel, 12. Episode: Produziert von Ayaka Matsumoto und Greg Peters. Unter der Regie von Masato Maeda: Spieldauer 54 Minuten, FSK 12. https://www.netflix.com/title/80212301 (letzter Abruf: 21.07.2019).//Boisu [Boys and Girls In The City] Vol. 2 (26.02.2012). Netflix: TV-Mini-Series (Video On Demand). 3. Staffel, 12. Episode: Produziert von Ayaka Matsumoto und Greg Peters. Unter der Regie von Masato Maeda: Spieldauer 54 Minuten, FSK 12. https://www.netflix.com/title/80212301 (letzter Abruf: 21.07.2019).]

Comment: Thank you very much! Got it - I usually think multiple tickets might be considered annoying, but I guess, it's either for those who actually take the time and try to fix things :) So if I wanted the last name of producer and director to be set in smallcaps (just like author/editor e.g.), I should open a new ticket for that right? :)

Comment: @user168390 In general yes. It's easier for those answering questions when they can focus on only one thing (and you don't scare away people who only know about one of the issues you ask about). It also makes the questions more relevant for other people with a similar problem, because the question and answers are focussed on one thing. Before you ask a new question, check out if `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}` might be enough for you